# Why are there two different openings for Nadeko in Bakemonogatari?

Tags: monogatari-series

In Bakemonogatari, there are two different openings for Nadeko - the one with a hat and the one without it.

[image: left: hat version; right: no-hat version]

Is there any specific reason why that is?

Comment: Is the music also different?

Comment: @Maroon the hat is the only different between those two

Comment: @ShinobuOshino the Tiger Paw on her foot is different and the Shadows down her side including the bear and the corner of the white thing on the right. also if you look at the arm with the Pokie you can see it's been moved across though that is more of a graphical correction

Answer (score 3):

Studio SHAFT has almost a custom of changing openings even after they first aired. For example currently airing Mekakucity Actors have slightly different openings for their first 3 episodes, usually changing text fonts or scenes slightly. The reason for this is simply lack of time management, where they don't put much time to "quality check" the opening with director and they keep changing it until they like it.

That is probably case with Nadeko's OP. Someone of power simply didn't like the version with hat, so they remove it.

Answer (score 3):

As every character in the Monogatari series holds a metaphorical reference to the oddity he/she meets, the opening shows Nadeko's evolution.

**Senjougahara** has a **stapler representing a crab's claw** as we see in first episode.

**Mayoi** carries **her bag as a snail shell,** and her shadow itself becomes a snail - her symbol when she sticks to Koyomi as they walk with Senjougahara in episode 5 of Bakemonogatari.

**Kanbaru** carries **her own arm as the representation of the Rainy Devil,** mistaken for a monkey's paw within the arc.

**Hanekawa** **has her ears turning into that of a cat**, approaching her own symbol.

**Nadeko has her jacket and hat**, representing a **snake's second skin.** As she seems to be shedding her skin (becoming a totally opposite character in the second season, thus explaining the change of her outfit), the disappearance of those in the OP scene of her season one arc shows she's been released from the snake's bindings.
As the OP is highly subjective and reveals her inner thoughts, it might mean that she feels safe whenever she reaches Koyomi to ask for help (at the end of the first episode of the arc), revealing how deeply she trusts him.

Comment: "Hanekawa has her ears turning into cat's one, approaching Kanbaru's symbol." seems to be wrong, so I change it to the current version.